# UIColelctionView Pinterest style layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am following a pinterest style UICollectionViewLayout tutorial, however the tutorial has a Photos Model and my photos are in URL format so I am not able to have a return function in the delegate method. How can I return my image to fill this requirement. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nboTP.png)

```
extension PagesCollectionViewController : PinterestLayoutDelegate {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return userArray[indexPath.row].photoURL
    //   return photos[indexPath.item].image.size.height
}



   import Foundation
  import Firebase
  import FirebaseDatabase

 struct Users {
var email: String!
var uid: String!
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var location: String?
var photoURL: String!
var biography: String?
var key: String?
var name: String!
var phoneNumber: NSNumber?
var password: String!


init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

    if let snap = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
        self.password = snap["password"] as! String
        self.email = snap["email"] as! String
        self.uid = snap["uid"] as! String


        self.phoneNumber = Double(snap["phoneNumber"] as! String) as? NSNumber
        self.location = snap["location"] as! String
        self.photoURL = snap["photoURL"] as! String
        self.biography = snap["biography"] as! String
       self.name = snap["firstLastName"] as! String

    }

}

init(data: NSDictionary) {

    self.password = data.value(forKey: "password") as! String
    self.email = data.value(forKey: "email") as! String
    self.uid = data.value(forKey: "uid") as! String
    self.phoneNumber = Double(data.value(forKey: "phoneNumber") as! String) as? NSNumber
    self.location = data.value(forKey: "location") as! String
    self.photoURL = data.value(forKey: "photoURL") as! String
    self.biography = data.value(forKey: "biography") as! String
    self.name = data.value(forKey: "firstLastName") as! String
}

init(email: String, uid: String) {
    self.email = email
    self.uid = uid
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
}
}
```

Comment: The delegate method returns a CGFloat which will define the height of the cell. You are returning a URL which is a String. You must return a CGSize.

Comment: You may have to download the image and assign it to a UIImage view First In order to get the size of the image

Comment: @ggtechllc have you got the solution

Comment: Yes but it was a completely different approach that I took

Comment: Email me and I can share if you would like